# Applescript: Accessing the comments object in Keynote

Tags: applescript, keynote

I'm trying to determine whether Apple has exposed the 'comments' object in Keynote ^6.5 I've checked its Applescript dictionary, but I don't see any object with that name.  My purpose is to build a script that reads and logs the comments made in a Keynote file into a log file.

Comment: I posted this question on the AppleScript list server and the consensus is that comments are not exposed in the Keynote Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

For Keynote 6.5.2 and above:

`tell application "Keynote" to get presenter notes of current slide of front document
tell application "Keynote" to get presenter notes of slide 1 of front document
tell application "Keynote" to get presenter notes of slides of front document`